# ToolTip is null. How do I access it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

In my custom control I want to programmaticaly enable or disable tooltip depending on options. Here is how my icon defined in template:

```
<Image x:Name="PART_IconImage" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" 
                                   ToolTipService.ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
```

I'm using this code to access ToolTip and to enable/disable it:

```
// Enable tooltip when caption not shown
            if (this.IconImage != null)
            {
                var toolTip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(this.IconImage) as ToolTip;

                if (toolTip != null)
                    toolTip.IsEnabled = this.CaptionVisibility.HasValue
                                        ? (this.CaptionVisibility.Value == Visibility.Collapsed)
                                        : (this.ParentToolbar.CaptionsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed);
            }
```

GetToolTip returns null. Any idea why?

P.S. I was following this advice here: [How to programmatically access ToolTipService of a Silverlight FrameworkElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571049/how-to-programmatically-access-tooltipservice-of-a-silverlight-frameworkelement)
But it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `ToolTipService.GetToolTip` is returning null, as opposed to returning something other than a `ToolTip`?

I did a quick experiment with code similar to yours and found that `ToolTipService.GetToolTip` returned a string.  I was of course binding `ToolTipService.ToolTip` to a string dependency property.  I suspect you're also getting a string back from `GetToolTip`, but the `as ToolTip` you have added after the call to this method nulls out this string.

One way to programmatically disable the tooltip is to bind it to a property on the view-model which contains the tooltip text if the tooltip should be shown or null if the tooltip should not be shown.

Alternatively, you can use a `ToolTip`, instead of a string, as the tooltip for your control.  That way you should be able to access the `ToolTip` object and enable/disable it in your code above:

```
<Image x:Name="PART_IconImage" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Comment: You probably correct on that it returned string. I didn't check that. I don't wan't to bind since it is not public property in my control. I already solved this by removing XAML completely and writing code to do `ToolTipService.SetToolTip` when I need. I will mark your answer because it will work your way and also I already have my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply bind property below with a bool property?

```
ToolTipService.IsEnabled
```

Then whenever you want to disable/enable simply change the binded property

< `Image ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}">`

Also take a look at [How do you disable tooltips in code at runtime](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98471070-06ee-481e-b586-08b9fb4f15eb/)

Comment: Then take a look at link I mentioned it might help you

Comment: He has a point, right now you're willing to use binding but not MVVM. It's hackish.

Comment: I deleted all my previous comments. Silverlight doesn't expose `IsEnabled` as dependency property. And even if it did - I don't want to expose such properties in my control